# Несколько функций в map

Tags: python

Возможно ли в `map()` использовать несколько функций? То есть, например, у меня есть список `[1, 0, -3, 10]`. Я хочу: к числам меньше `0` прибавлять `2`, к числам равным нулю прибавлять `3`, к положительным числам прибавлять 2. Могу ли я реализовать все это в одном map или же мне придется прописывать три разных map для каждого случая? (цикл for использовать нельзя).

Если придется прописывать три разных случая, можно ли в итоговом списке сохранить порядок чисел из исходного списка?

Comment: все, что вы описали легко реализуется единственной функцией

Comment: "_к числам меньше 0 прибавлять 2_", "_из отрицательных чисел вычитать -2_" - эти два условия и действия идентичны.

Comment: Спасибо! исправил, не доглядел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map(lambda x: 3 if x == 0 else x + 2 if x < 0 else x - 2, list_)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_fun(n):
  if n < 0:
    return n+2
  elif n == 0:
    return 3
  else:
    return что там еще

x = map(my_fun, [1,0,-3,10])
```

Comment: Это, конечно, верно, но не очень интересно. Хотелось бы подход с использованием только map, filter, lambda итд

Comment: @НикитаПодсеваткин Это, хотя бы, читается. А код, в первую очередь, пишется для людей.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, не могу с Вами не согласиться, однако задание предполагало использование именно функционального подхода через функцию map в одну строчку.